# Solve $(1-x^2)y^{\prime\prime} + xy^\prime-y=0$ using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck with this problem because the equation has 2 singular regular points $x =-1$ and $x=1$, so how can I get the solution?